# Find at least one record from two where conditions from a join table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a `course` table

```
course_id  name          type
1          Arthematic    Maths
2          Geometry      Maths
3          Chemistry     Science
4          Biological    Science
5          Hisotry       Social
6          Independence  Social
```

more records like this
And `student` table

```
student_id    name          
    101       David
    102       Tony
    103       Skye
    104       Nicole
    105       Ossof
```

And a `student_course` many to many join table

```
id student_id course_id
1  102         2
2  102         3 
3  101         1
4  101         2
5  101         3
6  103         2
7  103         5
8  104         3
9  105         1
10 104         5
```

I am trying to find all the students who have both Maths and Science course types for a given course IDs. Means I need to find students who have atleast one Maths type course and atleast one Science course type for given input of course ids
I have written this query but this gives student ids for any student who either Maths or Science or both

```
select sc.student_id from student_course sc left join course c on sc.course_id = c.id
where c.type = 'Maths' OR c.type = 'Science' and c.id IN (1,3,5)
group by  sc.student_id having count(sc.student_id) >= 2
```

Comment: Side note: Using a `LEFT JOIN` to `course` is pointless here as your `WHERE` requires `type` and `id` to have non-`NULL` values, and thus a row **must** be returned and so you have an implicit `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it would be better to use `in` operator to avoid logical mistakes related to parentheses, also you should use `count` with `distinct` to avoid counting the same types.

```
select sc.student_id
from student_course sc inner Join course c on sc.course_id = c.id
where c.type In ('Maths','Science') and c.id in (1,3,5)
group by sc.student_id 
having Count(distinct c.type) = 2
```

[db<>fiddler](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=988d47ec7b0446a6132aa183698a1911)

Result:

| student_id |
| --- |
| 101 |